# xml schema Validation script prevent nesting

Tags: xml, xsd, web-config

I am trying to create an xsd file run against our web.config files. I am trying to catch human error and prevent nesting of tags. Example of bad xml:

```
<applicationSettings>
   <app.MySettings>
       <setting name="FirstName" serializeAs="String">
         <value>John</value>
            <setting name="LastName" serializeAs="String">
               <value>Smith</value>
            </setting>
       </setting>
   </app.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

You will notice the Setting "LastName" is nested inside of "FirstName". The correct format is:

```
<applicationSettings>
   <app.MySettings>
      <setting name="FirstName" serializeAs="String">
         <value>John</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="LastName" serializeAs="String">
         <value>Smith</value>
      </setting>
   </app.MySettings>
</applicationSettings>
```

So, I'm trying to create a schema to run it against. I have this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="applicationSettings">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="app.mysettings">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="setting">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                                                <xs:sequence>
                                                    <xs:element type="xs:short" name="value"/>
                                                </xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                                                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="serializeAs"/>
                                            </xs:choice>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Something is wrong because I get back its valid which it shouldn't be? If this is the wrong way to do this (using schema) please let me know of a better way.

Thanks!

D H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to design schema for the above xml instance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns="http://example.com"
 targetNamespace="http://example.com"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="applicationSettings">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="app.MySettings"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="value" type="xs:short"/>
<xs:element name="setting">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="value"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="serializeAs" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="serializeAs" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="app.MySettings">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="setting" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Will this prevent the nesting of the tags? And don't you have to close <xs:schema>? using </xs:schema>

Comment: Yes. If you pass an instance which has nesting tag, it will through a XML Validation Error. Updated the answer with </xs:schema>.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was somewhat right, full schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 elementFormDefault="qualified"
 attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="applicationSettings">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="app.MySettings"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="setting">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="value"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:attribute name="serializeAs" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="serializeAs" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="app.MySettings">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="setting" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```